# Using lazy initialisation with namespaces in Javascript

Tags: javascript, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

I'm running into a couple issues with JavaScript, namespaces and minification/concatenation. I have no control (at least I don't want to have any) over in which order the files get concatenated. Using a namespace function which simply returns an object when given a string such as 'com.example.ExampleClass', a 'class' might not be defined when I need it in another one.

Suppose I have a DocumentProvider object, which needs functionality from EventDispatcher. But, in my current setup, DocumentProvider is concatenated before EventDispatcher. I want to define this functionality on the prototype, so I can't extend it in the constructor.

So, my proposed solution is to use lazy initialization:

- Define a top level `namespace(alias, factory)` function
- Use pseudo-overloading in namespace to either assign a factory to the
  specified name or return the object created by the factory

Alternatively I could split it up in `define(alias, factory)` and `import(alias)`. Better for readability, more polluting of global space.

My question is: am I overengineering? Are there better, simpler, more 'standard' solutions to this problem? And what's the risk of namespace functionality (with a different implementation) being added to the language?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) It may save you a lot of time.